# What is this component and what is it used for?

Tags: identification, components

Today I opened an old adapter to salvage the transformer and found this component which I also desoldered.

What is this component and what is it used for?

[image: Component]
[image: Component on PCB]

It seems to have a resistance of 10 Ohms as shown and it's labeled as R1, but the joule is confusing me, so I don't think it's a regular resistor. I haven't been able to find anything online.

Comment: It's a power resistor, probably ceramic. J might be a tolerance code.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's very helpful.

Comment: [What is a Fusible Resistor?
A Fusible Resistor is a wire-wound resistor that is designed to burn open easily when the power rating of the resistor is exceeded.

Use of Fusible Resistors
In this way, a fusible resistor serves dual functions. When the power isn't exceeded, it serves as a resistor limiting current. When the power rating is exceeded, it functions as a fuse, burning up, and becoming an open in the circuit to protect components in the circuit from excess current.](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/What-is-a-fusible-resistor)

Comment: I have one similar to yours in-line with the AC plug on a dead AA battery charger. It is open. I thought the rough depression on one side might be from it blowing out, but since yours isn't blown, I guess they are made that way.

Comment: I dont think thats necessarily a fusible resistor. That package is a standard ceramic package for high power resistors, and that depression is indeed just from manufacturing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a 10 ohm resistor hence the label on the PCB called "R1".

The "J" stands for 5%.

> *what is it used for?*

It's a power resistor and may be used for many things so I would urge you to read [Wikipedia's page on resistors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor) and hopefully it might enlighten you given that you have the device in your hand whilst all I have is a picture of it.

Comment: And since it reads "KOA" and "W1" the manufacturer might be KOA Speer and product series might be BWR1.

Answer (score 16):

10 ohm +/-5% wirewound resistor (probably inductive, perhaps fusible but it's hard to tell). Called a "cement" resistor. Made by KOA (Nagano, Japan-based company). If it's 13mm long, then 1W rating. J is the JIS or EIAJ standard code for +/-5% tolerance.

Here is a [datasheet](http://www.koaspeer.com/pdfs/BGR-BWR-BSR.pdf).

Answer (score 7):

That's a 10Ohm **fusible cement resistor** with a  5% tolerance --->(J).

Comment: The [datasheet](http://www.koaspeer.com/pdfs/BGR-BWR-BSR.pdf) doesn't say anything about "fusible". What does "fusible cement" mean?

Comment: It means that the cement based body of the resistor can act as a good fusing agent against high inrush current (last feature point in the datasheet)